# StratifiedKFold in python giving error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

in python I am importing

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

>>> cv = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_folds'

>>> print('The sklearn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
The sklearn version is 0.18.1.
```

I have sklearn 0.18.1. Any idea why i m getting this error?

Comment: [`sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn-model-selection-stratifiedkfold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter for number of folds is `n_splits`, not `n_folds`

See:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html

Comment: now I tried cv = StratifiedKFold(n_split=5) but for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv): gives me error TypeError: 'StratifiedKFold' object is not iterable

Comment: I am using code from https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/gpu_acceleration/bosch.py

Comment: try instead `for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv.split(X, y)):`

Comment: See: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html